# Open PDF in WebView with file size more than 1MB

Tags: android, webview

I want to load **PDF** in **WebView** from the **URL**.
I have used Google Doc. viewer using "http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" this link followed by PDF url. 
But it cannot load the **PDF which size is more that 1MB**, and 
I want to **show PDF in application only, not in other PDF Viewer application.**

Can you suggest me how I can achieve this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-display-PDF-files-inside-an-Android-application-instead-of-loading-in-WebView-by-appending-PDF-URL-with-a-Google-DOCs-Url-and-launching-a-third-party-PDF-rendering-application-installed-in-the-device-Are-there-any-good-free-PDF-rendering-libraries-available/answer/Piyush-Gupta-288?srid=hNkz7

Answer (score 0):

The only free solution I know is to use this API (21 and newer):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html